# matAutocomplete don't save value -- Typescript

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, autocomplete, angular-material

*My form dosen't work for autocomplete input, matAutocomplete don't save value -- Typescrip.
I don't understand what is the problem. Can you suggest me something, or some idea?*

*My html code:*

```
<form [formGroup]="Myform" (ngSubmit)="save()" class="col s12" materialize>

     <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input formControlName="username" id="username" type="text" class="validate" placeholder="Enter Username" minlength="3" maxlength="20"
            required="" [ngClass]="{invalid: invalidInputs}">
        </div>
      </div>
    <input formControlName="country_id" id="country_id" matInput placeholder="Select Country" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto"
      autoActiveFirstOption [formControl]="country_id">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option id="country_id" *ngFor="let country of filteredOptionsCountry | async" [value]="country.name">
        {{ country.name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete> 

    <input formControlName="region_id" id="region_id" matInput placeholder="Select Region*" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto4"
      autoActiveFirstOption [formControl]="region_id">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto4="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let region of filteredOptionsRegion | async" [value]="region.name">
        {{ region.name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>     

   <input formControlName="city" id="city" matInput placeholder="Select City*" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto1"
      autoActiveFirstOption [formControl]="city">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto1="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let city of filteredOptionsCity | async" [value]="city.name">
        {{ city.name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete> 

    <div id="register_user_button_container" class="row">
      <button id="register_user_button" type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light">
        Register
      </button>

    </div>
  </form>
```

*And my ts code like this:*

```
filteredOptionsCountry: any;
  country_id: FormControl = new FormControl();

  filteredOptionsCity: any;
  city: FormControl = new FormControl('');
   filteredOptionsRegion: any;
  region_id: FormControl = new FormControl('');

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    private userService: UserService,
    private roleService: RoleService,
    private cs: CountryService,
    private rs: RegionService,
    private citys: CityService) {

    this.Myform = new FormGroup({
     'username': new FormControl(),
      'country_id': new FormControl(''),
      'city': new FormControl(''),
     'region_id': new FormControl('')
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.filteredOptionsCountry = this.country_id.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(val => this.filterCountry(val))
    );
    this.filteredOptionsCity = this.city.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this.filterCity(value))
    );
    this.filteredOptionsRegion = this.region_id.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this.filterRegion(value))
    );

    this.cs.getAllCountry().subscribe(
      countryes => {
        this.countryes = countryes.map((country) => {
          return new Country(country);
        });
      }
    );

    this.rs.getAllRegion().subscribe(
      regions => {
        this.regions = regions.map((region) => {
          return new Region(region);
        });
      }
    );

    this.citys.getAllCity().subscribe(
      cityes => {
        this.cityes = cityes.map((city) => {
          return new City(city);
        });
      }
    );
  }


  filterCity(val: string): City[] {
    if (val) {
      let filterValue = val.toLowerCase();
      console.log(this.cityes)
      return this.cityes.filter(city => city.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(filterValue));
    }

    return this.cityes;
  }


  filterCountry(val: string): Country[] {
    if (val) {
      let filterValue = val.toLowerCase();
      console.log(this.countryes)
      return this.countryes.filter(country => country.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(filterValue));
    }

    return this.countryes;
  }


  filterRegion(value: string): Region[] {
    if (value) {
      let filterValueRegion = value.toLowerCase();
      return this.regions.filter(reg => reg.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(filterValueRegion));
    }
    return this.regions;
  }
  save() {

    let newUser= this.Myform.value
    console.log(newUser)

  }
}
```

In the console, it shows nothing for autocomplete input.

Please any suggestion for fix this problem? Thank you

[image]

console.log(this.MyForm)
[image]

Comment: You are binding MatAutocomplete to 'country_id' of the COMPONENT but you are printing out 'this.Myform.value' and 'country_id' is always new FormControl(''). Please try 'console.log(this.country_id);'.

Answer (score 0):

Ok first of all you can use onSelectionChange:

`<mat-option (onSelectionChange)="updateForm(city.id, city)"`

Now in your component you want to update your form with patchValue:

```
private updateForm(_id: any, _formControlName: any){
  this.form['controls'][_formControlName].patchValue(_id);
}
```

If a event fires twice do `<mat-option (onSelectionChange)="updateForm($event, city.id, city)"`

And

```
private updateForm(_event: any, _id: any, _formControlName: any){
   if (_event.isUserInput) {
     this.form['controls'][_formControlName].patchValue(_id);
   }
}
```

**EDIT**

`<mat-option (onSelectionChange)="updateForm(city.id, 'city')" // where your city automcomplete is`

For country it look like:

`<mat-option (onSelectionChange)="updateForm(country.id, 'country_id')"`

Comment: Cannot read property 'patchValue' of undefined--> in ts code:   private updateForm(city: any, country_id: any, region_id: any, _formControlName: any) {
    this.Myform['controls'][_formControlName].patchValue(
      {
        city: this.city,
        country_id: this.country_id,
        region_id: this.region_id
           }
    )
}

Comment: and html code:   <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="updateForm(city)"

Comment: Can you make a console.log(this.Myform) for me? Then you can see the controls.

Comment: What you basicly need is:
`this.Myform['controls']['country_id'].patchValue( SelectedCountryID) `

Comment: SelectedCountryID in my code what is? I set the photo

Comment: They ID you give in the html. Make sure you have your name of the formcontrol and the id you want to change it to in the function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165238/discussion-between-a-bina-and-swoox).

Comment: Thank You, but the result is: controls: {uesrname: FormControl, country_id: FormControl, city: FormControl, region_id: FormControl}

Comment: Swoox, I change my code like this:   updateForm(_event: any, city: any, country_id: any, region_id: any) {
    if (_event.isUserInput) {
      this.Myform['controls']['country_id'].patchValue(country_id);
      this.Myform['controls']['city'].patchValue(city);
      this.Myform['controls']['region_id'].patchValue(region_id);
      console.log(_event)
    }
  }  --> In console.log(_event) i see my value when I click. But the event dosen' work.   <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="updateForm($event, city.id, 'city_id')"